# Avoid Captcha authentication when file_get_contents() from localhost

Tags: web-crawler, file-get-contents

For my thesis work I need to collect data from different article-based websites. When I use `file_get_contents()` on other sites from my localhost script it works fine for first few times for some sites. However, some sites present a Captcha authentication prompt to validate the unauthorized bot access after 5-10 tries, so my script can't run properly.

I just want to get the full page content by using `file_get_contents()` from the other site from my localhost script. I also tried to set the user agent, but with no progress.
I am using this to set the user agent:

```
<?php ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1468.0 Safari/537.36"); ?>
```

How can I avoid this type of Captcha authentication when I am using `file_get_contents()` from my localhost a huge amount of times to get data from remote web pages?

Comment: The website owners want to allow human users and exclude automated scrapers like yours. Why should we help you to bypass their policies?

Answer (score 0):

That would defeat the whole purpose of captcha, wouldn't it? Captcha was exclusively designed to avoid robots like yours to clog the system with requests and form submissions.